# Centos Nano Upgrading

Tags: centos, linux

I'm having a few issues with the default version of Nano...Its extremely buggy and when I scroll between characters they mysteriously change without my editing.

How do I update my nano version? The version is 2.0.9 and it doesnt have anything more recent when I do yum update nano.

The nano webpage shows 2.2.6.

Whats the best way of upgrading this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's more likely that your TERM variable isn't set correctly, rather than there being a defect in nano.  Basically, if the TERM variable is not right for your terminal program, then there will be screen drawing errors (i.e., if your terminal is emulating VT100, but your TERM is set to xterm, it'll use codes that will not redraw the screen correctly, especially for an application like nano)

What client are you using to access the box, at least in terms of using nano?  Can you do something like `echo $TERM` (before invoking nano) and tell us what the result is?

Update:

The terminal config files are in /usr/share/terminfo somewhere.  On my CentOS 6 box, I see that the x/xterm-256color file is part of the "ncurses-base-5.7-3.20090208.el6.i686" package.  Do you have that package installed?  Run `rpm -qa |grep ncurses` and it should show up (I think nano only depends on the ncurses-libs package, so ncurses-base may not be installed).  If not, run "yum install ncurses-base".

Comment: Using terminal with MacOS X $TERM = xterm-256color

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm running centos 5 with this installed ncurses-5.5-24.20060715...yum update ncurses didnt update anything

Comment: When you get to your CentOS box, do an "echo $TERM".  What does that say?  You said you did the "echo $TERM" on the Mac, but I'm not sure if you did it on the Linux box.